# How to make a list of the findings in a text file by using Regular Expression with R?

Tags: r, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I have to transform all the arguments in a text character vector into an easy-to-reference format: A list that has 3 column (presenter, time and text) by using R (Sorry I should've been clearer).

For example, presenter should be

```
# HARPER'S
```

time should be

```
# [Day 1, 9:00 A.M.]
```

and text should be the rest in the argument.

I need to calculate the number of arguments in the text (each start of

```
# HARPER'S [Day 1, 9:00 A.M.]
```

is an argument). I want to Create a new list object named 'arguments' and each element of the list is a sublist that contains three elements ('presenter', 'time' and 'text').

Then extract the presenter name and time into two character vectors (also remove indentation), and leave the 'presenter' element and 'time' element in the sublist for that argument.

```
This is the text: 
 [1] "HARPER'S [Day 1, 9:00 A.M.]:  When the computer was young, the word hacking was"  
  [2] "used to describe the work of brilliant students who explored and expanded the"    
  [3] "uses to which this new technology might be employed.  There was even talk of a"   
  [4] "\"hacker ethic.\"  Somehow, in the succeeding years, the word has taken on dark"  
  [5] "connotations, suggestion the actions of a criminal.  What is the hacker ethic,"   
  [6] "and does it survive?"                                                             
  [7] ""                                                                                 
  [8] "ADELAIDE [Day 1, 9:25 A.M.]:  the hacker ethic survives, and it is a fraud.  It"  
  [9] "survives in anyone excited by technology's power to turn many small,"             
 [10] "insignificant things into one vast, beautiful thing.  It is a fraud because"      
 [11] "there is nothing magical about computers that causes a user to undergo"           
 [12] "religious conversion and devote himself to the public good.  Early automobile"    
 [13] "inventors were hackers too.  At first the elite drove in luxury.  Later"          
 [14] "practically everyone had a car.  Now we have traffic jams, drunk drivers, air"    
 [15] "pollution, and suburban sprawl.  The old magic of an automobile occasionally"     
 [16] "surfaces, but we possess no delusions that it automatically invades the"          
 [17] "consciousness of anyone who sits behind the wheel.  Computers are power, and"     
 [18] "direct contact with power can bring out the best or worst in a person.  It's"     
 [19] "tempting to think that everyone exposed to the technology will be grandly"        
 [20] "inspired, but, alas, it just ain't so."                                           
 [21] ""                                                                                 
 [22] "BRAND [Day 1, 9:54 A.M.]:  The hacker ethic involves several things.  One is"     
 [23] "avoiding waste; insisting on using idle computer power -- often hacking into a"   
 [24] "system to do so, while taking the greatest precautions not to damage the"         
 [25] "system.  A second goal of many hackers is the free exchange of  technical"        
 [26] "information.  These hackers feel that patent and copyright restrictions slow"     
 [27] "down technological advances.  A third goal is the advancement of human"           
 [28] "knowledge for its own sake.  Often this approach is unconventional.  People we"   
 [29] "call crackers often explore systems and do mischief.  The are called hackers by"  
 [30] "the press, which doesn't understand the issues."                                  
 [31] ""                                                                                 
 [32] "KK [Day 1, 11:19 A.M.]:  The hacker ethic went unnoticed early on because the"    
 [33] "explorations of basement tinkerers were very local.  Once we all became"          
 [34] "connected, the work of these investigations rippled through the world.  today"    
 [35] "the hacking spirit is alive and kicking in video, satellite TV, and radio.  In"   
 [36] "some fields they are called chippers, because the modify and peddle altered"      
 [37] "chips.  Everything that was once said about \"phone phreaks\" can be said about"  
 [38] "them too."
```

I have tried to calculate the length of the argument.

```
length(grep("^([A-Z]+'*[A-Z]*)", text_data))
arguments = list(presenters = regmatches(text_data, regexpr("^([A-Z]+'*[A-Z]*)", text_data)), time = regmatches(text_data, regexpr("(\\[.*\\])", text_data)), text =  regmatches(paste(unlist(text_data), collapse =" ")), regexpr("(:\\s.*)", regmatches(paste(unlist(text_data), collapse =" "))))
text_data
```

The length of the list "arguments" should be 55.

An example of the output would be [example data output format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SSDj.png)

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: What is your expected output? Can you give an example of the output?

Comment: @Yusufsn Thank you for asking. I want to output a list that includes the three parts (presenter, time and text), and then extract the presenter name and time into two character vectors.

Comment: @Yusufsn Thank you for your response. I have included an example output of the first argument in the description.

Comment: You can use `(?P<presenter>[A-Z|']+).\[(?P<time>\w.+)\].\s+(?P<text>[\w\W]*?)(?=\n\n|\Z)` to extract your variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your input:

```
text_data = """HARPER'S [Day 1, 9:00 A.M.]:  When the computer was young, the word hacking was
used to describe the work of brilliant students who explored and expanded the
uses to which this new technology might be employed.  There was even talk of a
\"hacker ethic.\"  Somehow, in the succeeding years, the word has taken on dark
connotations, suggestion the actions of a criminal.  What is the hacker ethic,
and does it survive? 

ADELAIDE [Day 1, 9:25 A.M.]:  the hacker ethic survives, and it is a fraud.  It
survives in anyone excited by technology's power to turn many small,
insignificant things into one vast, beautiful thing.  It is a fraud because
there is nothing magical about computers that causes a user to undergo
religious conversion and devote himself to the public good.  Early automobile
inventors were hackers too.  At first the elite drove in luxury.  Later
practically everyone had a car.  Now we have traffic jams, drunk drivers, air
pollution, and suburban sprawl.  The old magic of an automobile occasionally
surfaces, but we possess no delusions that it automatically invades the
consciousness of anyone who sits behind the wheel.  Computers are power, and
direct contact with power can bring out the best or worst in a person.  It's
tempting to think that everyone exposed to the technology will be grandly
inspired, but, alas, it just ain't so.

BRAND [Day 1, 9:54 A.M.]:  The hacker ethic involves several things.  One is
avoiding waste; insisting on using idle computer power -- often hacking into a
system to do so, while taking the greatest precautions not to damage the
system.  A second goal of many hackers is the free exchange of  technical
information.  These hackers feel that patent and copyright restrictions slow
down technological advances.  A third goal is the advancement of human
knowledge for its own sake.  Often this approach is unconventional.  People we
call crackers often explore systems and do mischief.  The are called hackers by
the press, which doesn't understand the issues.

KK [Day 1, 11:19 A.M.]:  The hacker ethic went unnoticed early on because the
explorations of basement tinkerers were very local.  Once we all became
connected, the work of these investigations rippled through the world.  today
the hacking spirit is alive and kicking in video, satellite TV, and radio.  In
some fields they are called chippers, because the modify and peddle altered
chips.  Everything that was once said about \"phone phreaks\" can be said about
them too."""
```

Extract your three variables using `regex`:

```
import re
argument = re.findall("(?P<presenter>[A-Z|']+).\[(?P<time>\w.+)\].\s+(?P<text>[\w\W]*?)(?=\n\n|\Z)",text_data)
```

Just in case if you want to make them a dictionary:

```
mydict = {'presenter':[],'time':[],'text':[]}
for i in argument:
    mydict['presenter'].append(i[0])
    mydict['time'].append(i[1])
    mydict['text'].append(i[2])
```

Or if you want to save them in `csv` file:

```
import csv
with open("filename.csv","w") as mycsv:
    writers = csv.writer(mycsv)
    header = ['presenter','time','text']
    writers.writerow(header)
    for item in argument:
        writers.writerow(item)
```

To load your `csv` file:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
df
```

Output:

```
   presenter |  time              | text
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0   HARPER'S |  Day 1, 9:00 A.M.  | When the computer was young, the word hacking ...
1   ADELAIDE |  Day 1, 9:25 A.M.  | the hacker ethic survives, and it is a fraud. ...
2   BRAND    |  Day 1, 9:54 A.M.  | The hacker ethic involves several things. One...
3   KK       |  Day 1, 11:19 A.M. | The hacker ethic went unnoticed early on becau...
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Is there anyways to do it in RStudio with R instead of Python? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With the way you want to capture the given text, this regex should do your job as it captures the presenter, time and text into three groups and using `re.findall` it finds all text and puts them into a list where each of those three information are present in a tuple as single element in the list. Check this regex demo,

```
(.*?)\s+(\[[^[\]]*\]):\s*([\w\W]*?)(?=\n\n|\Z)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/v4boQ4/1)**

Sample Python codes,

```
import re

s = """HARPER'S [Day 1, 9:00 A.M.]:  When the computer was young, the word hacking was
used to describe the work of brilliant students who explored and expanded the
uses to which this new technology might be employed.  There was even talk of a
\"hacker ethic.\"  Somehow, in the succeeding years, the word has taken on dark
connotations, suggestion the actions of a criminal.  What is the hacker ethic,
and does it survive? 

ADELAIDE [Day 1, 9:25 A.M.]:  the hacker ethic survives, and it is a fraud.  It
survives in anyone excited by technology's power to turn many small,
insignificant things into one vast, beautiful thing.  It is a fraud because
there is nothing magical about computers that causes a user to undergo
religious conversion and devote himself to the public good.  Early automobile
inventors were hackers too.  At first the elite drove in luxury.  Later
practically everyone had a car.  Now we have traffic jams, drunk drivers, air
pollution, and suburban sprawl.  The old magic of an automobile occasionally
surfaces, but we possess no delusions that it automatically invades the
consciousness of anyone who sits behind the wheel.  Computers are power, and
direct contact with power can bring out the best or worst in a person.  It's
tempting to think that everyone exposed to the technology will be grandly
inspired, but, alas, it just ain't so.

BRAND [Day 1, 9:54 A.M.]:  The hacker ethic involves several things.  One is
avoiding waste; insisting on using idle computer power -- often hacking into a
system to do so, while taking the greatest precautions not to damage the
system.  A second goal of many hackers is the free exchange of  technical
information.  These hackers feel that patent and copyright restrictions slow
down technological advances.  A third goal is the advancement of human
knowledge for its own sake.  Often this approach is unconventional.  People we
call crackers often explore systems and do mischief.  The are called hackers by
the press, which doesn't understand the issues.

KK [Day 1, 11:19 A.M.]:  The hacker ethic went unnoticed early on because the
explorations of basement tinkerers were very local.  Once we all became
connected, the work of these investigations rippled through the world.  today
the hacking spirit is alive and kicking in video, satellite TV, and radio.  In
some fields they are called chippers, because the modify and peddle altered
chips.  Everything that was once said about \"phone phreaks\" can be said about
them too."""

argument = re.findall(r'(.*?)\s+(\[[^[\]]*\]):\s*([\w\W]*?)(?=\n\n|\Z)', s)
print(argument)
```

Prints the list which contains tuple having three items `presenter`, `time` and `text`

```
[("HARPER'S", '[Day 1, 9:00 A.M.]', 'When the computer was young, the word hacking was\nused to describe the work of brilliant students who explored and expanded the\nuses to which this new technology might be employed.  There was even talk of a\n"hacker ethic."  Somehow, in the succeeding years, the word has taken on dark\nconnotations, suggestion the actions of a criminal.  What is the hacker ethic,\nand does it survive? '), ('ADELAIDE', '[Day 1, 9:25 A.M.]', "the hacker ethic survives, and it is a fraud.  It\nsurvives in anyone excited by technology's power to turn many small,\ninsignificant things into one vast, beautiful thing.  It is a fraud because\nthere is nothing magical about computers that causes a user to undergo\nreligious conversion and devote himself to the public good.  Early automobile\ninventors were hackers too.  At first the elite drove in luxury.  Later\npractically everyone had a car.  Now we have traffic jams, drunk drivers, air\npollution, and suburban sprawl.  The old magic of an automobile occasionally\nsurfaces, but we possess no delusions that it automatically invades the\nconsciousness of anyone who sits behind the wheel.  Computers are power, and\ndirect contact with power can bring out the best or worst in a person.  It's\ntempting to think that everyone exposed to the technology will be grandly\ninspired, but, alas, it just ain't so."), ('BRAND', '[Day 1, 9:54 A.M.]', "The hacker ethic involves several things.  One is\navoiding waste; insisting on using idle computer power -- often hacking into a\nsystem to do so, while taking the greatest precautions not to damage the\nsystem.  A second goal of many hackers is the free exchange of  technical\ninformation.  These hackers feel that patent and copyright restrictions slow\ndown technological advances.  A third goal is the advancement of human\nknowledge for its own sake.  Often this approach is unconventional.  People we\ncall crackers often explore systems and do mischief.  The are called hackers by\nthe press, which doesn't understand the issues."), ('KK', '[Day 1, 11:19 A.M.]', 'The hacker ethic went unnoticed early on because the\nexplorations of basement tinkerers were very local.  Once we all became\nconnected, the work of these investigations rippled through the world.  today\nthe hacking spirit is alive and kicking in video, satellite TV, and radio.  In\nsome fields they are called chippers, because the modify and peddle altered\nchips.  Everything that was once said about "phone phreaks" can be said about\nthem too.')]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. Is there a way to do in RStudio with R instead of Python?

Answer (score 1):

```
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)

text2df <- function(text) {
    idx <- c(1, which(text == ""), length(text))
    apply(matrix(c(idx[-length(idx)], idx[-1]), ncol = 2), 1, function(id1_id2) {
        presenter_text <- text[id1_id2[1]:id1_id2[2]]
        first_row <- paste(presenter_text[1:2], collapse = "") # presenter_text[1] can be ''
        presenter_name <- strsplit(first_row, split = " [", fixed = T)[[1]][1]
        presentation_time <- strsplit(first_row, split = "]: ", fixed = T)[[1]][1] %>% 
            gsub(paste0(presenter_name, " ["), "", ., fixed = T)
        presentation_text <- paste(c(
            gsub(paste0(presenter_name, " [", presentation_time, "]:"), "", first_row, fixed = T) %>% 
                stringi::stri_trim_left() # remove leading spaces
            , presenter_text[3:length(presenter_text)] %>% .[!is.na(.)] # filter NA if only one row of text
        ), collapse = "")
        data.table(presenter = presenter_name, time = presentation_time, text = presentation_text)
    }) %>% rbindlist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
matchObj = re.search( r'(.*?)\[(.*?)\](.*\s)', line)
print(matchObj.group(1))
print(matchObj.group(2))
print(matchObj.group(3))
```

This Might help 
Using group you can extract the characters if you want to change some logic you can change in the "()" brackets